# mutationobserver multiple node DOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, mutation

I am trying to use mutationobserver for multiple nodes.

> __w2_modal_wrapper_14

Have childnodes but 15,16,17 don't have any nodes. they will automatically load when scroll goes down. And I want a check on every nodes `__w2_modal_wrapper_14`, `__w2_modal_wrapper_15`, `__w2_modal_wrapper_16` and `__w2_modal_wrapper_17` and more as the web will load.

So please suggest any solution.

```
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
  var list = document.getElementById('#__w2_modal_wrapper_14');

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {  
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
       alert("change");
      }
    });
  });

  observer.observe(list, {
    attributes: true, 
    childList: true, 
    characterData: true
  });
```

[image]

Comment: Please share some code so we can help. This is nothing we can use.

Comment: Hi I have added a code that is used for single node

Comment: @caisah can check it once please, else you need something more.